# C++ Parsing char array as a script file (syntax)

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax, char

I have made a simple Script reading class in C++ which allows me to read and parse scripts.
Basically there's a FILE class, which then I proceed to open with "fopen".

In functions I proceed to call "fgetc" and "ftell" to parse the script file as needed, note this ain't an interpreter.
Every script file is supposed to follow a syntax, but this is why I'm asking here for a solution.

Here's how a script looks like:

```
# Script File Comment
USERNAME    = "Joe"
PASSWORD    = "pw0001"
ACCESSLEVEL = 3

DATABASE    = ("localhost",3306,"db","user","password")
```

Basically I have a few functions:

```
// This function searches for "variables"
nextToken();

// After I have the variable, e.g: USERNAME, PASSWORD, ACCESSLEVEL or DATABASE
// I proceed to call this function
// This function reads the char array for (,-{}()[]=) these are symbols
readSymbol();

// In a condition I check what "token/variable" I got and proceed to read 
// it accordingly
// e.g; for USERNAME I do:
readString(); // reads text inside "
// e.g; for ACCESSLEVEL I do:
readNumber(); // reads digits until the next char ain't a digit
// e.g; for DATABASE I do:
readSymbol(); // (
readString(); // 127.0.0.1
readSymbol(); // ,
readNumber(); // 3306
readSymbol(); // ,
readString(); // db
readSymbol(); // ,
readString(); // user
readSymbol(); // ,
readString(); // password
readSymbol(); // )
```

I would like to be able to read a variable declaration like this:

```
DATABASELIST = {"data1","data2","data3"}
or
DATABASELIST = {"data1"}
```

I could easily do readSymbol and readString to read for 3 different string definitions inside the variable, however this list is supposed to have custom user data, like 5 different strings, or 8 different strings - depends.

And I seriously have no idea how can I do this with the parser I wrote.
*Please note that I am basing this in some Pseudo code I took from a scripter for this type of format, I have the pseudo code extracted from IDA, if you would like to see it for better understanding post here*

Here's an example of my "readSymbol" function.

**READSYMBOL**

```
int TReadScriptFile::readSymbol()
{
    int currentData = 0;
    int stringStart = -1;

    // Check if we can't read anymore
    if (end)
        return 0;

    while (true)
    {
        // Basically get chars in the script
        currentData = fgetc(File);

        // Check for end of file
        if (currentData == -1)
        {
            end = true;
            break;
        }

        if (stringStart == -1)
        {
            if (isdigit(currentData) || isalpha(currentData))
            {   
                printf("TReadScriptFile::readSymbol: Symbol expected\n");
                close();
                return 0;
            }
            else if 
                (
                currentData == '=' || currentData == ',' || 
                currentData == '(' || currentData == ')' || 
                currentData == '{' || currentData == '}' || 
                currentData == '>' || currentData == '<' ||
                currentData == ':' || currentData == '-'
                )
            {
#ifdef __DEBUG__
                printf("Symbol: %c\n", currentData);
#endif
                stringStart = ftell(File);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**NEXTTOKEN**

```
int TReadScriptFile::nextToken()
{
    int currentData = 0;
    int stringStart = -1;
    int stringEnd = -1;
    RecursionDepth = -1;
    memset(String, 0, 4000);

    // Check if we can't read anymore
    if (end)
        return 0;

    while (true)
    {
        // ** Syntax ** 

        if (isdigit(getNext()) || getNext() == -1)
        {
            printf("No more tokens left.\n");
            end = true;
            close();
            return 0;
        }
        // End
        // Basically get chars in the script
        currentData = fgetc(File);

        // Check for end of file
        if (currentData == -1)
        {
            end = true;
            break;
        }

        // Syntax Checking Part, this really isn't needed but w/e
        if (stringStart == -1)
        {
            if (currentData == '=' || isdigit(currentData))
            {
                printf("TReadScriptFile::nextToken: Syntax Error: string expected\n");
                close();
                return 0;
            }
        }

        // End Syntax Checking

        // It's a comment line, we should skip
        if (currentData == '#')
        {
            seekNewLn();
            continue;
        }

        // There are no variables, yet
        if (stringStart == -1)
        {
            // We found a letter, we are near a token!
            if (isalpha(currentData))
            {
                stringStart = ftell(File);

                // We might as well add the letter to the string
                RecursionDepth++;
                String[RecursionDepth] = currentData;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (stringStart != -1)
        {
            // Let's wait until we get an identifier or space

            // We found a digit, error
            if (isdigit(currentData))
            {
                printf("TReadScriptFile::nextToken: string expected\n");
                close();
                return 0;
            }
            // We found a space, maybe we should stop looking for tokens?
            else if (isspace(currentData))
            {
#ifdef __DEBUG__
                printf("Token: %s\n", String);
#endif
                break;
            }

            RecursionDepth++;
            String[RecursionDepth] = currentData;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I found a good example of the approach I followed here:

http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl1.html

Comment: I think you need a parser and a lexer. The parser would identify symbols, and the lexer would identify lexemes or tokens in your grammar. Unfortunately, that's not an easy subject (compiler theory was the hardest class I took in college). Perhaps it might be easier to use [Flex and Bison](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html). With Flex and Bison, you would only need to specify a grammar.

Comment: [`boost::spirit`](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) could also be a viable alternative.

Comment: This parser I'm basing my code from, which is actually decompiled from an ELF binary file was written by a big company named CipSoft. They didn't use any external classes or programs because it would take a lot of time and dedication to make the lexer and parser, instead they went for this simple script parser by searching for tokens, symbols, and identifiers in a char array. Hope you understand my concern.

Comment: Interesting thing though had one person in the company known how to use Lex and Yacc (Or Flex and Bison) they probably could have coded up a more extensible parser than what they got by hand. If you ever have a chance to sit down with some free time, I recommend learning Yacc and Lex. There is a Yacc and Lex for python as well called PLY (Python Lex and Yacc) although I have never personally used it

Comment: As for your question about `DATABASE_LIST`. After Finding the variable have you considered reading a symbol checking if it is `{` then in a loop do `readString()` add it to a `std::vector` then check for a `,` or `}`(using `readSymbol()`) . If it is a `,`(comma) then you go back and read another string add to the `vector` etc until you do finally reach `}` . When you are finished you'd have a vector (dynamic array) of strings that represent a `DATABASE_LIST`

Comment: Michael, if you could post that as an answer so I could solve this question! Thank you really, that was the exact way I had to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mechanism to deal with `DATABASE_LIST` would be this:

After finding the variable `DATABASE_LIST` read a symbol using `readSymbol()` checking if it is a `{` then in a loop do `readString()` add it to a `std::vector` (or some other suitable container) then check for a `,` or `}` (using `readSymbol()`) . If it is a `,`(comma) then you go back and read another string add to the vector etc. until you do finally reach `}` . When you are finished you'd have a vector (dynamic array) of strings that represent a `DATABASE_LIST`